# How to generate an XML with lxml.objectify

Tags: lxml

I am currently using amara 2 for XML work, but looking for a solution which works with Py3 and Py2, I made progress with lxml.objectify but have a problem on how to generate this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns="http://www.vinoxml.org/XMLschema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
<querycreator>
  <name>The Wine Cellar Book - version 15.1</name>
</querycreator>
```

With lxml and this code snippet I get the following.

```
doc_header = """<query></query>"""

doc = etree.ElementTree(etree.fromstring(doc_header))
docO = objectify.fromstring(doc_header)

objectify.SubElement(docO, "querycreator")
docO.querycreator.name = objectify.DataElement(u"The Wine Cellar Book - version %s"
                                               % 15.1)


<query>
  <querycreator>
    <name>The Wine Cellar Book - version 15.1</name>
  </querycreator>
</query>
```

With amara I can use a doc_header like this:

```
doc_header = """<query xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.vinoxml.org/XMLschema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"></query>"""
```

But using that I with lxml.objectify I get attribute error on docO.querycreator.

I also experimented with objectify.Elementmaker but couldn't make that working either.

Comment: Got a bit further, found the tostring param to get the xml declaration, now just need the namespace stuff.

Answer (score 0):

By using ElementMaker I got the namespace.

```
myE = objectify.ElementMaker(namespace="http://www.vinoxml.org/XMLschema",
                             nsmap={None : "http://www.vinoxml.org/XMLschema"})

docO = myE.query(myE.querycreator())

docO.querycreator.name = objectify.DataElement(u"The Wine Cellar Book - version %s"
                                               % 15.1)

objectify.deannotate(docO)
etree.cleanup_namespaces(docO)
print(etree.tostring(docO, pretty_print=True,
                     encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration=True))
```

I got the vinoXML namespace, not sure that I need :xsi and :xsd.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<query xmlns="http://www.vinoxml.org/XMLschema">
  <querycreator>
    <name>The Wine Cellar Book - version 15.1</name>
  </querycreator>
</query>
```